# iCalendar - how to display multiple lines in (outlook) calendar?

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar

I'm working on a small project to generate a .ics file containing event information that I can view in my Outlook calendar.  I can get the event to show up in Outlook, but I want to show multiple lines.  For example, for this .ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20131227T123500
DTSTART:20131227T080000
DTEND:20131228T170000
SUMMARY:Vacation
DESCRIPTION:abc
UID:1
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I want to show `Vacation` as the title and then right under it, I want to show some kind of description like `<abc>` similar to how meeting events are scheduled like this pic in outlook:

[image]
Is this possible?

Comment: Cant you export the meeting that corresponds to your pic ("Weekly 1-on-1) as an iCalendar stream ? Then are you sure that the "Call my office or cell" part of it comes from the summary or description and not from the LOCATION field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the newline.  For example:

`SUMMARY:Weekly 1-on-1\nCall my office or cell`

Be aware that there is a 72-character line length limit you may need to address if you put lots of information in the field.  You should also be aware that different clients might treat the newlines differently, for example Google Calendar appears to remove them from the summary field so will not result in the view that you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah..doesn't seem to work in Outlook or iCal on the Macbook.  That sux!!